# Specific information from tuple lists

Tags: haskell

I'm stuck on a exercise from a book where I have to take a database for a library and I have to find out if a book is currently being borrowed by checking a the database which is full of tuples of the form

```
type Person = String
type Book = String
type Database = [(Person,Book)]
```

the function I have to use is

```
borrowed :: Database -> Book -> Bool
```

where the Database is full of all of the books currently being borrowed, the Book is the book i'm searching for and it should return True if the book is being borrowed

Here's what I've got so far, ghci keeps telling me I have problems with matching types in the getTuple function but I can't figure out what's wrong

```
-- Database I will use for the function
exampleBase :: Database 
exampleBase =
    [ ("Alice","Tintin") , ("Anna","Little Woman") ,
      ("Alice","Asterix") , ("Rory","Tintin") ]

borrowed :: Database -> Book -> Bool
borrowed dBase book
    | getTuple dBase book == book = True
    | otherwise = False

getTuple :: Database -> Book -> Book
getTuple (x:xs) bk
    | x == null = "notBook"
    | (getBook x) == bk = bk
    | (getBook x) /= bk = getTuple xs bk

getBook :: (String,String) -> Book -> Book
getBook (first,second) bk
    | second == bk = bk
    | otherwise = "notBook"
```

Comment: Please add the error you are getting to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `x == null` won't work.

In Haskell, `null` is a *function*. It takes a *list* and tells you if the list is empty or not. So `null x` might do something. Except `x` here isn't a list, it's a *tuple*.

Perhaps you meant something more like

```
getTuple [] bk = "notBook"
getTuple (x:xs) bk
  | (getBook x) == bk = ...
  | (getBook x) /= bk = ...
```

Not sure why you're testing that condition twice, once with `==` and once with `/=`; you could simply replace the second one with `otherwise`.

For that matter, not sure why you need a separate `getBook` function; you could simply do

```
getTuple [] bk = "notBook"
getTuple ((person, book) : xs) bk = if book == bk ...
```

Then again, I'm not even sure why `getTuple` returns a `Book` (or the magic string `"notBook"` if not found), which `borrowed` then has to compare... when you could just return a `True` or `False` right from here.

```
borrowed [] bk = False
borrowed ((person, book) : xs) bk = if book == bk then True else borrowed xs bk
```

Answer (score 2):

This is very close to the solution, but lets address a few problems in your code:

1. Avoid in-exhaustive pattern matching

In Haskell we tend to avoid inexhaustive pattern matching as much as possible as such code can crash on runtime. For example, your getTuple function will crash given the empty list. The compiler will alert you of such cases when compiling with -Wall

2. Encode invariance in your types

Haskell offers data types to help you represent invariance. For example, if you want to represent a 0 or 1 value, use Maybe. For example: "notBook" is a valid name for a book, so if you didn't find the value you were looking for you can use Nothing, and if you did you can use Just bk.

3. Pay attention to type mismatches

In your getTuple function you try to compare x with null, null in Haskell is a function that checks if a list is empty,so you have a tyoe mismatch there.

4. Name things well

getTuple is probably not a great name for your function :) I'm sure you can come up with a more informative name.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this fixes your type errors:

```
getTuple (x:xs) bk
    | null xs = "notBook"
    | (getBook x) bk == bk = bk
    | (getBook x) bk /= bk = getTuple xs bk
```

But I'd like to advise you that returning a special value (`"notBook"`) for exceptional cases is not a good style. You can simplify your solution to just return `True` if you found the book, or try the next one, or finally return `False`.

Answer (score 1):

`null` is a function, not a value.

You can't do this

```
x == null
```

But you can do this

```
null x
```

*Except* that `x` is also not a list!

I think you meant to check if the list is empty, which can be don't using pattern matching

```
getTuple [] _ = ....
```

This would come before the line you already have.